# Problems with Polarizationidentity

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

I just cant get it right.

Prove  $<x,y> = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{\lambda^4 = 1} \lambda ||\lambda x+y||^2$

$$\lambda ||\lambda x+y||^2 = \lambda<\lambda x+y,\lambda x+y> = \lambda(<\lambda x,\lambda x>+<\lambda x,y>+<y,\lambda x>+<y,y>)$$

$=\lambda(||x||^2 + \bar\lambda<x,y>+\lambda<y,x>+||y||^2) = \lambda||x||^2 + <x,y>-<y,x>+\lambda||y||^2 $

$= \lambda(||x||^2+||y||^2) + <x,y>-<y,x>$

Im missing something but i dont know where

Comment: You are missing a $|\lambda|^2$ in front of $||x||^2$ after the 3rd equal sign. Then use the fact that second and third term in that expression are each other's complex conjugate to write the whole () as the product of a () with its own complex conjugate.

Comment: I assumed that $|\lambda|^2 = 1 $ is that wrong? Also <x,y> - <y,x>  as a product? Im confused